# How to install free SSL on subdomain lumen/laravel on Cpanel?

Tags: laravel, ssl, cpanel, lumen, shared-hosting

I just wanna ask on how can I install a free SSL (wildcard) on my subdomain URL on cPanel that is built on Lumen.

My Subdomain is pointed on path public_html/*lumen_app/public folder and free SSL is requiring to make a .well-known/acme-challenge folder on public_html and when I verify it the page cannot be accessed by the ACME server.

Help is greatly appreciated. TIA!

Answer (score 0):

when you make subdomain in cPanel , cPanel make directory for this in file manager and you must make .well-known/acme-challenge on that directory . this is root directory for your subdomain .

for install free SSL try this site [sslforfree](https://www.sslforfree.com/) and you can install to sub domain in

cPanel - SECURITY - SSL/TLS

but you can install let’s Encrypt extension on cPanel by this command :

```
yum -y install letsencrypt-cpanel
```

and install SSL on domain and subdomain in cPanel Simply

Comment: when you Create a Subdomain , cPanel make directory by Subdomain name in public_html and you can make .well-known/acme-challenge directory in that .

Comment: Yea I did that but the acme server cannot verify my subdomain URL

Comment: did you get error ? can you open verify file by URL ?

Comment: Yes it says the page cannot be found. I downloaded the key from free ssl and uploaded it to .well-known/acme-challenge/*key file*

Comment: what is a verify url ? in free ssl site two link for verify what is it ? is that the you path ?